# Computing a fractional matching of maximum product in a bipartite graph

Tags: optimization, matching

Given a bipartite graph $(X\cup Y, E)$ with edge weights, it is easy to find a matching in which the product of weights is maximum: replace each edge weight with its logarithm, and find a matching in which the sum of weights is maximum.

Now, we would like to find a *fractional matching* which maximizes the product of values.
<sub>A fractional matching is an assignment of a fraction in $[0,1]$ to each edge, such that for every vertex, the sum of fractions of edges adjacent to it is at most $1$ (a matching is a special case of a fractional matching in which all fractions are in {0,1}).</sub>

The product of values is defined as follows:

- For each vertex $x\in X$, the value of $x$ is the weighted mean of the weights of edges adjacent to $x$. I.e., if it is adjacent to $e_1, e_2, e_3$, their weights are $w_1,w_2,w_3$, and their fractions in the fractional matching are $f_1,f_2,f_3$ (where the sum $f_1+f_2+f_3\leq 1$), then $v(x) = w_1 f_1 + w_2 f_2 + w_3 f_3$.
- We are looking for a fractional matching $f$ in which the product of values of vertices of $X$ is maximum.

Here, the trick of replacing weights with their logarithms does not work. Is there a different solution?

Comment: Are the fractions a part of the edge itself? or are they encoded in the vertex? that is, can one edge have different fraction values or only one?

Comment: If its only one, then we can simplify this problem by replacing their weights with $wf$, and then looking at maximizing the multiplication of the sums, instead of the means.

Comment: @nirshahar A fractional matching assigns a fraction to every edge. I edited the question to make it clearer.